# Get lower value through multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables loan(custno,acno & clearbal) & customer (custno,pan & name). Custno is common in both tables.I want to generate PAN wise data.For which I have build below mentioned query to get pan wise loan outstanding, I want to have customer name in output, but several pans are mentioned in different customer IDs, So

if i add name in same query it splits the record.
Is possible to incorporate customer name which is having lower id like
if "aaa" pan in in cusid 1 & 2 so cistomer nume in 1 should be displayed & group by should be done on "aaa"
sample details

Customer Table

```
Custno Pan Name
1 aaa Kevin
2 bbb peter
3 aaa Josh
```

Loan Table

```
Custno acno clearbal
1 20 100
2 21 50
3 22 200
```

Output I am getting through Query

```
Pan Count Bal
aaa 2 300
bbb 1 50
```

What I want is

```
Pan Name Count Bal
aaa Kevin 2 300
bbb peter 1 50
```

```
select c.pan,count(L.Acno) as Count,sum(L.ClearBal) as bal 
from LOAN as L 
inner join customer as C
on L.CustNo=c.CustNo where l.clearbal<0 
group by c.PAN 
order by bal desc
```

I have tried below mentioned query but output skips records having same pan card.

```
select c.name,c.pan,count(L.Acno) as Count,sum(L.ClearBal) as bal from LON20190629 as L inner join customer as C
on L.CustNo=c.CustNo inner joiN
  (
    SELECT pan, MIN(CustNo) MinPoint
    FROM customer
    where len(pan)>6
    GROUP BY PAN
  ) tbl1
  ON tbl1.PAN = C.PAN
WHERE tbl1.MinPoint = C.CustNo and and l.ClearBal<0 group by c.PAN,c.Name order by bal desc
```

Comment: This is a variation of the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] type of problem. Follow that tag to see many past solutions for it.

Comment: And, if you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: please provide answer query of my problem , i really struggling to get it resolved.